# Is .NET Core compatible with COM?

Tags: com, .net-core

I am trying to understand the implications of starting a project on .NET core.  One of the requirement I am facing is to use a .NET library that is leveraging [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model#.NET).

So is COM supported by .NET core (obviously, assuming the OS is Windows)?

I understand that .NET Core is built for interoperability between different OS.  But I was wondering if it is to be expected that there are Windows-specific features that may be included for the windows releases such as COM compatibility.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core is developed to be cross platform and running also on Linux and Mac. COM is a windows specific thing and will not be supported in .NET Core

Comment: Thanks Juergen, I appreciate your reply.  I was expecting that maybe .NET Core could keep some windows specifics, such as COM interraction capabilities.  It is still pretty new and I am understanding that no information about COM and .NET Core probably means it's not supported then!  Thanks again.