# how to use Foxpro MTDLL COM object in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I've created a MTDLL COM object in Foxpro and want to use it in ASP.NET Core, so far I've been unable to find a solution and packaging it with Nuget didn't work either whereas I can use this same dll easily in standard ASP.NET. Is there any way to use a Foxpro DLL COM object in ASP.NET Core? or Is there any difference between ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET in using COM objects?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt if COM is supported out of the box https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341362/is-net-core-compatible-with-com and if it is, it will be unlikely COM would work on OSX and Linux without tweaks. It looks like [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731389/how-can-i-add-a-com-dll-reference-in-my-net-core-project-based-on-beta8#comment74509194_43731542) managed to do so with some trickery but you have to experiment on your own first to get an [mcve] that you could include in your question.

Comment: Thanks  rene, We are trying to build a web application with the latest microsoft and javascript technologies, 
But a huge part of our current business module is written in Foxpro and in the first step, we also wanted to use this business module along with our new code which is totally written in .NET. 
So we are trying to use our business module as COM objects and use them in ASP.NET Core.
So do you think there is any way to use COM objects in any language( other than .NET) is usable or will be usable(in the future that .NET Core is expanding) in .NET Core?

Comment: If you really need COM I would stick to the latest .Net Framework  and not yet migrate to .Net Core. Or you really need to create an Proof of Concept that helps you finding the issues and ask a specific question about things you run into. With a bit of luck Hans or one of the other brilliant minds around here will spot your specific  question and address that code problem for your. Your current question is too broad to be really answered. If you have a Microsoft Support contract (comes with your MSDN license) you might try to contact MS directly and hire them.